# How can I specify a script in Bamboo OnDemand?

Tags: bamboo

A screen shot of the interface is here

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/bamboo.png

I find it a little confusing it's not exactly clear how I can specify my script in the OnDemand version. What should go in the textbox?  So far I have not seen a way to upload build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The Script is just the name of the script you want to call.  It needs to live on the agent.  Normally, you would sync/checkout the script from your source code repository.